# Positive lookbehind with a matching group to be extracted

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

```
testString = ("<h2>Tricks</h2>"
              "<a href=\"#\"><i class=\"icon-envelope\"></i></a>")
import re
re.sub("(?<=[<h2>(.+?)</h2>\s+])<a href=\"#\"><i class=\"icon-(.+?)\"></i></a>", "{{ \\1 @ \\2 }}", testString)
```

This produces: `invalid group reference`.

Making the replacement take only `\\1`, only extracts `envelope`, that makes me think that the lookbehind is ignored. Is there a way to extract something from lookbehind?

I'm looking forward to produce:

```
<h2>Tricks</h2>
{{ Tricks @ envelope }}
```

Comment: You created a character class (a set of characters that is allowed to match) consisting of `<`, `h`, `2`, `>`, etc. there.. Don't use `[..]` unless you want to create a set of characters for a match (`\s`, `\d`, etc. are pre-built character classes).

Comment: Looks like you *really* want to use a HTML parser instead. Mixing Regular expressions and HTML get's real painful, really really fast.

Comment: I am trying to write a complex F&R for Sublime Text editor, to replace some of the stuff within my files. And, without that `[..]`, `.search` found nothing.

Comment: Without the character class, the lookbehind is not allowed because you are not allowed to use variable-width patterns in a lookbehind (no `+` or `*`). *with* the character class the lookbehind no longer matches what you think it matches.

Comment: @psycketom ST2 isn't stopping you from using an HTML library if it's more suited to your purposes for this F&R :) (of course, you could look at the `regex` library, which supports variable length look ahead/behind assertions)

Comment: @JonClements Could you point me into a HTML library direction? Have never seen such plugin before.

Comment: Look at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ - have a play with that

Comment: @MartijnPieters, mind adding an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @psycketom: There you go, expanded into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you really want to use a HTML parser instead. Mixing Regular expressions and HTML get's real painful, really really fast.

In your regular expression, you created a character class (a set of characters that is allowed to match) consisting of <, h, 2, >, etc. here:

```
[<h2>(.+?)</h2>\s+]
```

which could have been written as:

```
[<>h2()+.?/\s]
```

and it would match the same characters.

Don't use [..] unless you want to create a set of characters for a match (\s, \d, etc. are pre-built character classes).

However, even if you were to remove the brackets, the lookbehind is not allowed. You are not allowed to use variable-width patterns in a lookbehind (no + or *). So, *with* the character class the lookbehind no longer matches what you think it matches, *without it* the lookbehind is not permissable.

All in all, just just [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead.